# Is it possible to authenticate the youtube/vimeo video embeding

Tags: python, django, youtube, youtube-api, vimeo

I'm re-writing my video sharing script in django. Lets say you became a user on my site, you already have a video called "[C++ programmer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x1TsOHyJPpw&feature=related)" on youtube, you want to import it to my site, I just want to make sure that it's your video and you are not using someone else's video to promote your channel.

Therefore I cannot create embedding forms because embedding codes are available to everyone.

I want to authenticate the process, maybe something like: "**Sign in with your youtube vimeo account to import your videos.**"

If i can add other video sharing site (metacafe, dailymotion etc) that will be great, but first I want to get it done with vimeo and youtube (i don't want to import the views and the rating, just the video, maybe the tittle and description. But if i can just import the video, it'll be great too)

Answer (score 1):

You can use achieve this using video feeds from the [Data Api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#Video_Feeds). So I'll assume that you know how to parse ATOM, RSS or JSON responses and that the user has logged in to your site with their google account, if they haven't they'll need to, otherwise this won't work. Having done that you can now get their youtube user id or username. With the username you can now query the data api with a uri such as this:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?alt=atom&author=user1   #we are looking at user1's channel
```

This responds with an atom feed. You have an option of RSS, ATOM or JSON. What you'll be looking for is an `id` tag inside an `entry` namespace eg.

```
<entry gd:etag='W/"A0IHQ347eCp7I2A9WhVTFEQ."'>
 <id>tag:youtube.com,2008:video:L_30JzRGDHI</id>
 ...
 <title>User1's first video</title>
```

`video:L_30JzRGDHI` is what you want. `L_30JzRGDHI` is the id of one of user1's videos. You can now collect all of user1's IDs and respective video titles and send the user to a page where he/she can select the videos to import to your site.

[Here's a page](http://gdata.youtube.com/demo/index.html) where you can play around with the api and see what details you can collect from the response. This is for youtube, I don't know about the other sites, you have the idea now, just see whether it can work with the other sites' APIs